# Elements won't stand still in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Okay so while testing a site in various browsers everything worked flawlessly except for internet explorer 7.  My problem is pretty weird one:  my menu elements won't stand still.  What I mean by that is that when I scroll the screen down my menu elements travel with me but only the link parts of them (all background stuff remains at the top) and when I scroll back up the menu elements are nowhere to be seen.  Is this a known bug in IE7?

I have some suspicions that the problem might lie in position attribute in css as I use position:relative and left/right:50% to center my menu elements.

Comment: Any chance something's getting `position: fixed`?

Comment: I suggest you use IE9 for IE7 testing (use `F12` to bring up the dev tools)

Comment: IE7 may require a top position value.

Comment: Without a link, jsfiddle, or the complete markup, anything we say is just a wild guess.

Comment: @Rob I understand that but your wild guesses gives me at least a baseline on where to start investigating.  I was hoping this is some widely know IE bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer myself.  Here it is for those who someday struggle with the same thing.

The culprit was as suspected position.  For some reason the relative positioned elements were treated as fixed or somehow seperated from the page layout so it "hovered" over everything while scrolling.  To remedy this is one should set the position of the container/wrapper of the page to relative.  So here it is in code:

```
#container{position: relative}
```

Huge thanks for all comments for prodding me in the right direction.

Comment: We would have been able to point you to that known bug in IE (among the multitude of others) if only we had a link or the markup.